# Comic about babies which turn into giant babies after feeding them with a baby formula

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a comic from the 90's, which I read when I was a kid where the babies are fed with a formula by a scientist which turns them into giants and they are made to work in sand mines. The scientist is forced to get out of the hotel where the people are protesting by changing his identity.

Comment: "The Food Of The Gods" was a book by H.G.Wells, which Marvel comics turned into a graphic comic. https://archive.org/details/TheFoodOfTheGods-GraphicComic

Comment: If I recall Wells' novel correctly, the giant kids weren't forced to work in any sand mines, nor did a hotel play any central part.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I'd be grateful if you could [edit] in any more details, like language or art style? Was it part of a larger company (Marvel, DC etc.) or a stand alone in-print?